# how can set email notifications for milestones in microsoft project 2010

Tags: microsoft-project-2010

Is there a way for setting automatic notifications for milestones in microsoft 2010? I would like to send a reminder email two days before a task ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sorry.  There is no native integration between Project 2010 and Outlook.

Comment: Saying something isn't possible can be the right answer, but that, alone, leaves the reader with a question of whether you're correct or just aren't familiar with a  solution. This kind of answer is always better if you can cite a source.

Comment: Unless the OP is using Project Server and Exchange integration is not possible.  If he is using Project Server, I imagine he would have mentioned it.  A quick [insert favorite search engine] search will show quite a few links for Project Server integration as well as a number of responses showing stand alone integration is not possible without a third party add-in.  Certainly I would appreciate it if you can cite a source that says that integration is possible without either Server or a third party product.